# Rails.application.assets.find_assets(file).digest_path doesn't work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I need to iterate through multiple images via a JS file, so I am making an http request to the server to match the filename to its client-side fingerprinted equivalent. I'm getting the fingerprinted file by passing the original file through `Rails.application.assets.find_asset(file).digest_path`

Example, in the rails console:

```
Rails.application.assets.find_asset("scene1.jpg").digest_path
```

returns

```
"scene1-b691b411ad644bcf2c84ef9e30f52db9ffdf57c18fadf99872dff3ebb81fa548.jpg"
```

However, when I run on my local server the output is simply `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Rails asset pipeline, assets are referenced with their [logical path](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#logical-paths). In this case, you can use embedded ruby ([erb](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets)) in your script by adding the `.erb` extension to the file, e.g.

```
var logo = <%= asset_path('logo.png') %>;
```

When this script is compiled, the ruby code will produce a reference to the asset with the current digest. The digest path is a "[fingerprint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care)" and will change as often as the assets themselves change.

To learn more about the asset pipeline, check out the [ROR guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/asset_pipeline.html) and the [Sprockets documentation](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-rack-based-asset-packaging).